# How can I generate output in SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I am currently studying SQL injection and I am trying to "steal" values out of a test-database. The database is consulted when a user tries to login to a website (regular POST formular, PHP) and it is kind of easy to bypass the login with the "usual" UNION stuff that can be found in typical guides.

Now my question is what ways are there to let MySQL give me the original data of the registered users instead of just letting me bypass the login? What I found so far is the "ExtractValue" function which I can give a new SQL query as argument and the result is then printed on the website. Are there any more or any better?

Comment: If the SQL server has mail enabled, it's fun to export the db to yourself via mail, and then hide hit by having it also flood the companies tech support with "fatal server error" messages =P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should better be asked at security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the Original Data of Users ( as you asked in the Question ), You can manually write `Select Queries` and try Union Based Injection as explained in these tutorials :

[Basic Union Based SQL Injection - SecurityIdiots](http://www.securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/Basic-Union-Based-SQL-Injection.html)

[Union Based SQL Injection - HackyShacky](http://hackyshacky.com/blog/sql-injection-union-based-tutorial/)

[SQL Injection in OWASP BWAPP - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIT-dv2n7sQ)

[Dumping a Complete SQL Database - InfoSec Institute](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/dumping-a-database-using-sql-injection/)

Apart from this, You can use automated tool - [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org/). It's documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki). Also there is a dump option in the tool for dumping complete database or selecively any tables you want in the database.